# How to update single column of tables which needs to be populated with multiple info

Tags: mysql

I'm having three tables as follows

1. manufacturing_detail_history
2. manufacturing_products_history
3. manufacturing_products

manufacturing_detail_history has two columns primarykey, description

manufacturing_products_history has two columns primarykey and manu_product_id (primary key is the manufacturing_detail_history primarky key reference)

manufacturing_products has three columns manu_product_id, name, type

Need to add a new column manu_product_names in manufacturing_detail_history and populate the manufacturing product names with comma separated values.

Not sure how to get the associated multiple manu_product_name for each manu_product_id and make it comma separated value and insert into manu_product_names column

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() [**function**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Can you please help me with SQL Insert query to populate the column product_names in table manufacturing_detail_history for all rows ???

Comment: create a sample data (http://sqlfiddle.com is great for that) and post what is your desire output

Comment: I have done the sql as follows  Select 
 T1.ID, T1.Desc, 
 T2.manu_product_id, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(T3.name ORDER BY T3.name ASC SEPARATOR ',')
From
 manufacturing_detail_history AS T1
inner join 
 manufacturing_products_history AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
inner join
 manufacturing_products AS T3 ON T3.manu_product_id = T2.manu_product_id
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Desc, T2.manu_product_id;

Comment: You can post it as an answer if that solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    T1.ID, T1.Desc, 
    T2.manu_product_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(T3.name ORDER BY T3.name ASC SEPARATOR ',')
From
    manufacturing_detail_history AS T1
inner join 
    manufacturing_products_history AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
inner join
    manufacturing_products AS T3 ON T3.manu_product_id = T2.manu_product_id
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Desc, T2.manu_product_id;
```